# Implement data virtualisation in a UWP ListView without duplicating items

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, windows-10, data-virtualization

I have a large `ListView` which is largely made `InkCanvas` objects, it turns out that `ListView` implements data virtualisation to "cleverly" unload and load items in the view depending on the visible items in the view. The problem with this is that many times the `ListView` caches items and when a new item is added it essentially copy items already added in the view. So in my case, if the user adds a stroke to an Inkcanvas and then adds a new InkCanvas to the ListView, the new canvas contains the strokes from the previous canvas. As reported [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/7817/strange-bug-in-listview-appending-new-items-readds.html) this is because of the data virtualisation. My ListView is implemented as follows:

```
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView x:Name="CanvasListView" IsTapEnabled="False"
                  IsItemClickEnabled="False"
                  ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Enabled"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

            <!-- Make sure that items are not clickable and centered-->
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <local:CanvasControl Margin="0 2"
                                             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                         MinWidth="1000" MinHeight="100" MaxHeight="400"
                                         Background="LightGreen"/>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Black" Height="2"></Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <InkToolbar x:Name="inkToolbar" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Background="LightCoral"/>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button x:Name="AddButton" Content="Add Page" Click="Button_Click"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="PageCountText" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

A full example can be found [**here**](https://github.com/daljit97/ListViewAddingTest) and here is a [**video of the issue**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxGdR.jpg). 
Indeed if I turn off data virtualisation (or switch to an `ItemsControl`) everything works brilliantly. The problem however is that with a very large list, this approach has a heavy impact on performance (with 60+ InkCanvas controls the app just crashes). So is there a way to retain data virtualisation while avoiding the duplication of items? I have tried with `VirtualizationMode.Standard` but items are still duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, we must first understand why this problem occurs.

`ListView` has a reuse container inside, it will not endlessly create new list items, but will recycle.

In most cases, such recycling is not a problem. But it's special for `InkCanvas`.
`InkCanvas` is a stateful control. When you draw on `InkCanvas`, the handwriting is retained and displayed on the UI.

If your control is a `TextBlock`, this problem does not occur, because we can directly bind the value to `TextBlock.Text`, but for the Stroke of `InkCanvas`, we cannot directly bind, which will cause the so-called **residue**.

So in order to avoid this, we need to clear the `state`, that is, every time the `InkCanvas` is created or reloaded, the strokes in the `InkCanvas` are re-rendered.

**1. Create a list for saving stroke information in `ViewModel`**

```cs
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // ... other code
    public List<InkStroke> Strokes { get; set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Strokes = new List<InkStroke>();
    }
}
```

**2. Change the internal structure of `CanvasControl`**

**xaml**

```xml
<Grid>
    <InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas" 
               Margin="0 2"
               MinWidth="1000" 
               MinHeight="300"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
    </InkCanvas>
</Grid>
```

**xaml.cs**

```cs
public sealed partial class CanvasControl : UserControl
{
    public CanvasControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        // Set supported inking device types.
        inkCanvas.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes =
            Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Mouse |
            Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Pen;

    }

    private void StrokesCollected(InkPresenter sender, InkStrokesCollectedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (Data != null)
        {
            var strokes = inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes().ToList();
            Data.Strokes = strokes.Select(p => p.Clone()).ToList();
        }
    }

    public ViewModel Data
    {
        get { return (ViewModel)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(ViewModel), typeof(CanvasControl), new PropertyMetadata(null,new PropertyChangedCallback(Data_Changed)));

    private static void Data_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.NewValue!=null && e.NewValue is ViewModel vm)
        {
            var strokes = vm.Strokes.Select(p=>p.Clone());
            var instance = d as CanvasControl;
            instance.inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokesCollected -= instance.StrokesCollected;
            instance.inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.Clear();
            try
            {
                instance.inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.AddStrokes(strokes);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }

            instance.inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokesCollected += instance.StrokesCollected;
        }
    }
}
```

In this way, we can keep our entries stable.

Comment: How do I assign the `Data` property of the `CanvasControl` in my `MainPage.xaml`?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out, I am still quite new to bindings. All I had to do was to add: `Data="{Binding}"`, to my `CanvasControl` in my main page.

Comment: Glad you found the solution, but I still need to apologize, this is my negligence